# How to manually construct complex matrix in Eigen library?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, complex-numbers

for example, the following code generate a complex matrix, with imaginary part equals 0

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
  MatrixXcf m(2,2);
  m<<1,2,3,4;
  cout<<m<<endl;
}
```

It outputs

```
(1,0) (2,0)
(3,0) (4,0)
```

But how to manually input arbitrary complex number matrix with nonzero imaginary part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `MatrixXcf` is just an alias for a matrix with element type `std::complex<float>`, you can provide arbitrary initializers of that type. In C++14, you have handy user-defined literals `i`, `if`, `il` to make imaginary units of the various floating point types. So the following works:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXcf m(2,2);
    m << 1.0f + 2.0if, 2.0f + 1.0if, 3.0f - 1.0if, 4.0f - 2.0if;
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

If you don't have the literals, you can just make your own and multiply:

```
const std::complex<float> If(0.0f, 1.0f);     // use x * I etc
```

I.e. the above code becomes:

```
m << 1.0f + 2.0f * If, 2.0f + 1.0 * If, 3.0f - 1.0 * If, 4.0f - 2.0 * If;
```

You have to take care to give all the literals the correct type, or operator overloading won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't understand, we must add `#include <complex>`? Then, in my example, I didn't include <complex>, why Eigen still can deal complex numbers?

Comment: and my mingw g++ says" error: 'literals' is not a namespace-name", is there a compiler option to enable C++14?

Comment: now I tried your first version with intel compiler icl, it works, But second version still not working

Comment: using `g++  -std=c++14`still emit errors like "c:\e/Eigen/src/Core/Functors.h:973:28: warning: 'template<class _Operation> clas
s std::binder2nd' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 struct functor_traits<std::binder2nd<T> >"

Comment: @user15964: THose are Eigen's problems, not yours. You can avoid printing those warnings by using `-isystem` rather than `-I` in GCC. Note that a "warning" is not the same as an "error".